# Mac optimizing no interface showing

Tags: macbook-pro

Latest macOS.
Recently reset smc.
After a restart got notification that Mac is optimizing something, it may take a while. In other articles people can still work, but in my case there is just a loading icon in the middle, that's it.
Waited for around an hour. But not sure it'll get better. I can move my cursor still.
Any way to get out of this?
[image]

Comment: "After restart" - did it restart normally, showing the Finder? What model Mac is this? Was it only after the SMC reset that this happened, or something else, like updating the OS?

Comment: It restarts, let's me insert the username and the password. Then shows "optimizing your Mac" badge and a spinner. It restarted the first time on it's own.

Comment: It's a 2019 mbp 16

Comment: I didn't update os, didn't see it update. Only if it updated during the night automatically

Comment: With anything like this, patience must be directly proportional to the length of time since your last backup. If that was only an hour ago, you can poke it & restart it as much as you like. If it was last year, then leave it alone, in case it just takes a long time. If it has hung, you just lost time, if it was truly busy doing something important, then rebooting it will probably break the process & you'll have to get into Recovery or restore.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down the power button, which should force it to shutdown. Then see if it will restart normally.

If that doesn't work, then try booting to Recovery. Check that the disk is OK, and then reinstall the OS.

Comment: Tried that couple of times. No change

Comment: How many reinstalls yielded no change @antonavy ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was somehow connected to the latest OS update. Some of my colleagues experienced the same issue.
What helped me and others, was:

1.Turn off wifi, that the MacBook can connect to.
2. Unplug power cord.
3. Reset SMC. (e.g. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295)